# Win32 multiline edit control loses carriage returns on SetWindowText()

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, controls

In my C++ Win32 GUI application I have a dialog with an edit control created from a dialog template:

```
EDITTEXT   IDC_EDIT_Id, X, Y, W, H,
    ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_WANTRETURN | WS_VSCROLL
```

Whenever I manually input multiline text with carriage returns and call `GetWindowText()` the retrieved text is broken into lines with `CR` and `LF` characters as expected. However when I try to put the same text back into the edit control with `SetWindowText()` the control displays that text as a single string.

Why does it exhibit such behaviour and how do I workaround this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you put the text back with SetWindowText, please make sure you are using \r\n for your newlines.

Works fine for me.

This will display the text on 2 lines:

```
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->SetWindowText(_T("Hello\r\nWorld!"));
```

> Hello
>   World!

This will display the text on 1 line:

```
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->SetWindowText(_T("Hello\nWorld!"));
```

> HelloWorld!

Comment: Yes, that was it. Now I normalize as following: first replace all "\n" with "", then all "\r" with "\r\n". Thanks a lot.